# bash script problem when run from desktop launcher

Tags: bash, shell-script, remote, sshfs

I have a script which does the following:

1. Connect via sshfs to a directory on a server
2. Within that directory, there is an encrypted volume. Open it to the device mapper.
3. Mount to a local directory (-o rw & -t ext4)

When I run this script from the terminal

```
sudo /.../myscript.sh
```

it runs with the expected behaviour.
However, when I run this script from a desktop shortcut, it runs, but with problems. In particular:

1. It appears to be mounted, and I can 'cd' into the mounted directory and list the contents. However, when I try to list the contents of a subdirectory, I get this message:

   ls: reading directory .: Input/output error
2. I don't seem to have write access to the directory. (I can't save files)

My desktop entry looks like this: (... is just for simplicity, again)

```
[Desktop Entry]
Name=myscript
Exec=mate-terminal -e "sudo /.../myscript.sh"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
```

Can anyone suggest why running the script from the shell seems to work, but running from the desktop shortcut gives me problems?

Comment: It's looks a liitle bit strange `Exec=mate-terminal` and `Terminal=false` together.

Comment: Maybe so, but I have used that combination before with no problems. Also, it's not as though the script doesn't run.

Comment: The environment this runs from is probably different. Try running `env` in the scripts to see what is set. If something fails, it should spit out some errors, so redirect stderr to a log file and post the results.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. I just tried this. The mount command triggers no output in the log file, either running the script directly or through the desktop entry. I also sent the output of 'env' to the log file. There is no difference except for the presence/absence of the 'LS_COLORS' line and a different path in the SUDO_COMMAND AND OLDPWD entries which I assume are not relevant.

Comment: Doesn't `gksudo /.../myscript.sh` do everything you want (assuming you're running Gnome)?

Comment: The script doesn't run properly with gksudo, even when executing from the terminal rather than the desktop entry.

Comment: Do `ps aux | grep sshfs` and check which user owns the process and wheather the process even exists. Also grep for `ssh` itself to see the process that keeps the connection open.

Comment: That looks like a big hint. There is a single difference in one line.. which also looks like what this user has mentioned: [link](http://askubuntu.com/questions/472411/ssh-x-a-oclearallforwardings-yes-running-on-my-machine)                                             'ssh -x -a -oClearAllForwardings=yes -2 user@host -s sftp' In the good connection, this line appears, controlled by root. In the bad connection, is is absent.

Comment: Just to clarify, having stepped through the other lines in the script: It appears that mounting the encrypted volume to the device mapper causes the ssh process

Comment: Just to clarify, having stepped through the other lines in the script: 'ps aux' shows both an ssh and an sshfs process get triggered at the start. But it appears that mounting the encrypted volume to the device mapper causes the ssh process to terminate, even though the sshfs stays active. And this only happens when the whole thing is run from the desktop shortcut. Although the disappearance of the ssh process is a conspicuous difference, I don't understand whether that is what makes the unencrypted directory behave as read only, or why running through a desktop shortcut makes any difference.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> Doesn't gksudo /.../myscript.sh do everything you want (assuming you're running Gnome)? –  Ken Sharp

... actually that does seem to work! Looks like this is an example of the mysterious problems mentioned here http://www.psychocats.net/ubuntu/graphicalsudo